# Why is the membership API adding an extra record to the aspnet_Applications table?

Tags: asp.net-membership

We are talkign ASP.NET 2.0. I have already added the applicationName attribute to my providers group in the web.config. But still, when I clear out all the tables and run the app, when I add a user, it adds 2 records, one with an ApplicationName= the actual application name I specified, and another with ApplicationName="/".

Now, I did notice that in forms I have the following code:

```
     <forms 
      loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
      timeout="20" 
      name=".ASPXAUTH" 
      defaultUrl="authenticated\home.aspx"  
      path="/"
      >
  </forms>
```

Is that path attribute responsible?

Answer (score 1):

No, '/' is root and is **always** present.